# Initializing array of struct in a struct after mmap

Tags: c, struct, shared-memory

I have a custom queue implementation as below

```
struct Customer {
    pid_t pid;
    int priority;
    int order;
};

typedef struct Customer Customer_t;

struct CustomerNode {
    int next;
    int filled;
    Customer_t customer;
};

typedef struct CustomerNode CustomerNode_t;

struct CustomerQueue {
    int front;
    int rear;
    int filledNodes;
    CustomerNode_t nodes[NODE_SIZE];
};

typedef struct CustomerQueue CustomerQueue_t;
```

and I need to map a `CustomerQueue_t *queue` as shared memory object, shared between processes. When I mmap first then initialize the struct, it gives segmentation fault.

```
void initQueue() {
    sharedQueue->front = 0;
    sharedQueue->rear = 0;
    sharedQueue->filledNodes = 0;
    sharedQueue->nodes = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i < NODE_SIZE; ++i) {
        sharedQueue->nodes[i] = (CustomerNode_t) { .next = -1, .filled = 0, (Customer_t) {-1, -1, -1 } };
    }
}
```

Mmap part

```
#define SHMQUEUE "SHMQUEUE"
...
CustomerQueue_t* sharedQueue;
int sharedQueueFd;
// open queue shared memory
sharedQueueFd = shm_open(SHMQUEUE, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
failChecker(sharedQueueFd, "Failed to open shared memory");
failChecker(ftruncate(sharedQueueFd, sizeof(CustomerQueue_t)), "Failed to ftruncate");

// map pizza new shared memory
sharedQueue = mmap(NULL, sizeof(CustomerQueue_t*), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, sharedQueueFd, 0);
if(sharedQueue == MAP_FAILED) {
   perror("Failed mmap");
   _exit(-1);
}
```

Here is the valgrind result when I changed sizeof(CustomerQueue_t) instead of its pointer. [image]
How can I solve it

Comment: I see no call to `mmap()` in the code. Kindly edit the question to include all relevant code and the error log.

Comment: @Haris added mmap part

Comment: `sizeof(CustomerQueue_t*)` - that's the size of a pointer, typically 4 or 8 bytes.  You probably meant to have it be `number_of_elements * sizeof(CustomerQueue_t)` ?  Or are you thinking you can share just the pointer between processes?

Comment: Actually I just want CustomerQueue_t in shared memory and I can use nodes in shared memory. I thing I found wrong solution like you mentioned by using pointer. However when I use `sizeof(CustomerQueue_t)` it fails with segmentation fault

Comment: When I debug it it fails `sharedQueue->nodes[i]` part. @Haris I added valgrind output after adding your suggestion

Comment: Is `sharedQueue` a global variable? Where's the `main()` function? What is `NODESIZE`?